# Howto build an array of array of objects in swift?

Tags: swift

Howto build an array of array of objects in swift ? 
The corresponding Java code looks like this :

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> arrayof_array_of_Objects=new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can embedded array inside another array like that:

```
var arr: [[String]] = [["1", "2", "3"], ["A", "B", "C"]]
```

or empty array:

```
var arr: [[String]] = [[String]]()
```

This is array of String objects but you can replace String with any object you like. You can also embed more array inside, just follow the logic.

Comment: ok I see, thanks. In my case it would be : var arrayof_array_of_Objects = [[NSObject]]();

Answer (score 1):

```
var arrayOf_array_of_Objects: [[NSObject]] = [[NSObject]]()
```